# fluidRow with multiple columns

Tags: r, shiny

How to align widgets in fluidRow without huge gaps. Take for example this code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    
    absolutePanel(
        
        id = "pn", top = 5, right = 5, class = "panel panel-default", 
        
        fluidRow(
            column(width = 3, selectInput("place_format", NULL, choices = character(0))),
            column(width = 7, selectizeInput("place", NULL, choices = character(0))),
            column(width = 2, actionButton("zoom","Zoom!"))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

if all `width` aren't`4` there is 'huge' gap between button and 2nd widget. And also after button there is a 'lot' of free space.

Comment: Align with what?

Comment: with edges of panel and each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of your `absolutePanel` is incomplete. Please see the details section in `?absolutePanel`

> The position (top, left, right, bottom) and size (width, height)
> parameters are all optional, but you should specify exactly two of
> top, bottom, and height and exactly two of left, right, and width for
> predictable results.

Please check the following example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(

  absolutePanel(
    id = "pn", top = "100px", left = "100px", right = "100px", bottom = "100px", class = "panel panel-default",
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 3, selectInput("place_format", NULL, choices = character(0), width = "100%")),
      column(width = 7, selectizeInput("place", NULL, choices = character(0), width = "100%")),
      column(width = 2, actionButton("zoom","Zoom!", width = "100%"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: yeah, had to define left edge to align with panel edges.